SQL query for particular output
I have an input table like below



Load_date
projected_date
total demand
rolling consumed demand




2020-01-01
2020-01-01
100
60


2020-01-01
2020-01-02
150
75


2020-01-01
2020-01-03
200
100


2020-01-01
2020-01-04
300
120


2020-01-01
2020-01-05
400
160



My output will be like this:



Load_date
projected_date
total demand
rolling consumed demand
Finished projected date




2020-01-01
2020-01-01
100
60
2020-01-03


2020-01-01
2020-01-02
150
75
2020-01-05


2020-01-01
2020-01-03
200
100
---


2020-01-01
2020-01-04
300
120
---


2020-01-01
2020-01-05
400
160
---



Can you please help me with the SQL query? I have tried to write query in Databricks SQL, but not getting this output. Actually it is a small part of my entire requirement.
The logic here is to calculate column Finished projected date, whenever the rolling consumed demand will exceed the total demand for a particular projected date, it will return that rolling consumed demand's corresponding projected date.
Like in the above table, the 2020-01-01 projected date has total demand of 100. But the rolling consumed demand reaches to 100 on projected date 2020-01-03. So, for 1st row it will return the finished projected date as 2020-01-03.
Similarly for projected date 2020-01-02, the rolling consumed demand exceeds the total demand on 2020-01-05. As 160 > 150. So the finished projected date would be 2020-01-05.

This problem can be solved with a self-join. Self-joins are inefficient and should be avoided if possible. You should seek a solution that uses a window function instead.
SELECT a.*, MIN(b.projected_date) as  [Finished projected date]
FROM InputTable a
LEFT JOIN InputTable b ON a.[total demand] <= b.[rolling consumed demand]
GROUP BY a.Load_date, a.Projected_date, a.[total demand], a.[rolling consumed demand] 

fiddle



Load_date
projected_date
total demand
rolling consumed demand
Finished projected date




2020-01-01
2020-01-01
100
60
2020-01-03


2020-01-01
2020-01-02
150
75
2020-01-05


2020-01-01
2020-01-03
200
100
null


2020-01-01
2020-01-04
300
120
null


2020-01-01
2020-01-05
400
160
null



