SQL query in order to get my desired output
I have an input table like this:



Start_date
future_date
current value
finished value




2020-01-01
2020-01-01
100
15


2020-01-01
2020-01-02
150
80


2020-01-01
2020-01-03
200
25


2020-01-01
2020-01-04
300
70


2020-01-01
2020-01-05
400
65



My intermediate output will be like this:
For projected date: 2020-01-01



Start_date
future_date
current value
finished value
rolling finished value
Finished date




2020-01-01
2020-01-01
100
15
---
2020-01-03


2020-01-01
2020-01-02
150
80
80
---


2020-01-01
2020-01-03
200
25
105
---


2020-01-01
2020-01-04
300
70
175
---


2020-01-01
2020-01-05
400
65
240
---



For projected date: 2020-01-02



Start_date
future_date
current value
finished value
rolling finished value
Finished date




2020-01-01
2020-01-01
100
15
---



2020-01-01
2020-01-02
150
80
---
2020-01-05


2020-01-01
2020-01-03
200
25
25
---


2020-01-01
2020-01-04
300
70
95
---


2020-01-01
2020-01-05
400
65
160
---



Similarly we have to derive the finished projected date for other projected dates
Final output will be:



Start_date
future_date
current value
finished value
Finished date




2020-01-01
2020-01-01
100
15
2020-01-03


2020-01-01
2020-01-02
150
80
2020-01-05


2020-01-01
2020-01-03
200
25
---


2020-01-01
2020-01-04
300
70
---


2020-01-01
2020-01-05
400
65
---



Can you please help me with the SQL query? I have tried to write query in Databricks SQL, but not getting this output. Actually it is a small part of my entire requirement.
The logic here is to calculate column Finished date, whenever the rolling finished value will exceed the current value for a particular projected date, it will return that rolling finished value's corresponding future date.
Like in the above table, the 2020-01-01 future date has current value of 100. The rolling finished value calculation starts 1 day after actual future date i.e. from 2020-01-02 onwards. The rolling finished value reaches to 105 on future date 2020-01-03. So, for 1st row it will return the finished date as 2020-01-03.
Similarly for future date 2020-01-02, the rolling finished value exceeds the current value on 2020-01-05. As 160 > 150. So the finished date would be 2020-01-05.

This question is very similar to the one you asked and I answered 22 hours ago  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78556532/sql-query-for-particular-output/78556639#78556639

Does this answer your question? SQL query for particular output

Yes, thanks a lot for your inputs. But now I am struggling to find out the rolling sum as frame is changing for each projected date. If you could please help? Many thanks @BartMcEndree

I haven't try it yet.
But should be look like this using sample table. You could this as an initial guide.
SELECT Date,
       Sales,
       SUM(Sales) OVER (ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as RollingCumulativeSales
FROM daily_sales
ORDER BY Date;

You could find refence and sample on this site. SQL Cumulative Sum: A Comprehensive Guide

Thanks but don't want to hardcode the frame with any fixed value. As it is only part of entire input @ygautomo
